# Constructing Dictionaries of dictionary in python

Tags: python, django

```
def home(request):
    context = populate_user_context(request, user.username)   

    val=amqp.consumer() 

    return render(request, "home.html", context, "Content-type:text/HTML", 200, None)



def populate_user_context(request,username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    context={'first_name':(user.first_name or None),
         'last_name':(user.last_name or None),
         'email':(user.email or None)
         }
    return context
```

When the function home is called. It builds up the context then calls consumer function. The consumer function returns a dictionary. If it returns a dictionary then i should call it again until it returns none(This part is not yet coded). Finally i have to add this to context and render to home.html.

Each dictionary is like {'a' : val1, 'b': val2}. Since i dont know how many dictionary it may return. What is the best way to get the dictionaries add to the context and render to home.html page. 
Earlier the question was not clear so i have edited.

Comment: *I want to construct a dictionary like `{{"a":val1,"b":val2}, {"a":val1,"b":val2}}`* - this is not a dictionary.

Comment: @Ahsanul Haque is right , thats a set of dictionaries.  Please be more specific

Comment: What for loop? Show a [mcve]

Comment: Perhaps what you wish for is a **list** of dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

For a dictionary you're missing the keys, unless you want to create a list (in which case you're using the wrong brackets).

List:

```
x = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]
```

Dictionary:

```
x= {"one": {"a": 1, "b": 2}, "two": {"a": 3,"b": 4}}
```